# Flushing or disabling cache on WordPress

Tags: login, cache, wordpress.com-hosting

I'm running a website on WordPress.com. It's on a subdomain (let's call it wp.domain.com) of my root domain (lets call it domain.com).

The main site on the root domain has a login/logout-routine that uses a cookie when logged in. The cookie is set to be available for all subdomain of domain.com.

I added the following code in functions.php to check if a user has the cookie or not:

```
add_action( 'init', 'block_access' );

function block_access() {

    if (!isset($_COOKIE["loggedin"]) && (!str_contains($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'no-access') && !(str_contains($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') || str_contains($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-login')))) {
            wp_redirect('/no-access/');
    }

}
```

I'm also checking if the URI does not contain "no-access" (page which you are directed to if not logged in), wp-admin or wp-login to avoid loops or admin loosing access.

Everything seems to be working fine, except that caching (Batcache) on WordPress.com is making some issues. It expires in 300 seconds which will create these scenarios:
If you login on the main site it may take up to 300 seconds to access wp.domain.com. If you logout you may access wp.domain.com for up to 300 seconds. If I flush cache in WP admin it works instantly.

Is there a way to disable caching on WordPress.com, or is there a better approach for this?